# Why am I getting 'Terminated due to timeout' error here?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I'm solving [this problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/circular-array-rotation) on Hackerrank.

John Watson performs an operation called a right circular rotation on an array of integers, [a[0],a[ 1]......a[n]].After performing one right circular rotation operation, the array is transformed from [a[0],a[ 1]......a[n]] to [a[n- 1],a[0]......a[n-2]].

Watson performs this operation 'k' times. To test Sherlock's ability to identify the current element at a particular position in the rotated array, Watson asks  'q' queries, where each query consists of a single integer, 'm', for which you must print the element at index  in the rotated array (i.e., the value of a[m] ).

Input Format

The first line contains 3 space-separated integers,'n' ,'k' , and , 'q' respectively. 
The second line contains 'n' space-separated integers, where each integer      'i' describes array element a[n] (where 0<=i

Output Format

For each query, print the value of the element at index 'm' of the rotated array on a new line.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {
/* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */   
int n,k,q,temp;
cin>>n>>k>>q;       //Input of n,k,q;
int arr[n],qur[q];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)    //Input of array
{
    cin>>arr[i];
}
    for(int i=0;i<q;i++)    //Input of query numbers
{
        cin>>qur[i];
}

for(int z=0;z<k;z++)
{
    temp = arr[n-1];
    for(int i=n-1;i>0;i--)
    {
        arr[i]=arr[i-1];
    }
    arr[0]=temp;
}

for(int i=0;i<q;i++)
{
    cout<<arr[qur[i]]<<endl;
}


return 0;
 }
```

The code's logic seems to be flawless. I'm a newbie.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because your code is too slow for hackerrank.

Comment: Please refrain asking questions about online code judge engines here. It's very  unlikely that anyone could tell you where you failed from their test cases, as these aren't disclosed usually. Even if what you tested was running at your local environment, you may have missed to test some edge cases which are applied in the online challenge. Be creative and try to find them. Additionally there's probably no value for such questions in the long term, other than cheating the online contest, and nothing is learned.

Comment: Hint: you don't have to do the rotations. Just adjust the value of `m`.

Comment: Some summation and modulo arithmetic makes this *much* simpler, and would probably eliminate a majority of the code. You should not have to rotate on each input rotation value. The purpose of the task is to figure out how to do *one* rotation ( btw `std::rotate` would be handy for that), and in reality, you don't even need to do the rotation. Once you have the final end-result rotation the query indexes can simply be adjusted against that.

Comment: The whole point of these coding challenges is to find a better way. Sure, you can easily brute-force through all the rotations for your test cases, but you are doing massive amounts of completely unnecessary work. Then you hit their test cases which are much bigger. So, what Pete just said, and I think the "modulo" operator might be handy. It looks like a percent sign.

Comment: Once you find yourself writing nested loops over the data, you're in trouble with many of these coding challenges.  You're basically implementing an `O(n*n)` approach, and those approaches usually result in timing out.

Comment: If I ask you to solve it by hand, are you sure that you will rewrite the full shifted array? That you will shift it *k* times? Can't you see something more subtle to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you don't really need to perform the rotation, you can use The Ancient Power of Mathematics.
(Performing the rotation can require 10 billion `arr[i]=arr[i-1]`s, and doing that 500 times would take a while.)

If you start with the sequence

```
Element: | 12 | 34 | ... | 56 | 78 |           (1)
Index:      0    1   ...   k-1   k
```

and right-rotate by one, you get

```
Element: | 78 | 12 | 34 | ... | 56 |           (2)
Index:      0    1    2   ...    k
```

or, changing the viewpoint just a little bit:

```
Element: | 12 | 34 | ... | 56 | 78 |           (3)
Index:      1    2   ...    k    0
```

There's a fairly simple relationship between the indices of the elements in (1) and (3), and you only need some arithmetic to get from one to the other.

Discovering the relationship and performing the arithmetic left as an exercise.

Comment: Thank you! The answer is very helpful! Also thank you for being so kind and helpful!! Much respect!